# How can I create a pdf for download in blazor wasm

Tags: pdf-generation, blazor-webassembly

In a blazor wasm, I want to create a pdf and make it downloadable. I tested [pdfflow](https://www.pdfflow.io/), but was only able to make it run in a console application. There are several commercial solutions (devexpress, syncfusion), but they are really expensive.
Next, I stepped over the blog post [Generate PDF files using an html template and Playwright](https://www.meziantou.net/generate-pdf-files-using-an-html-template-and-playwright.htm), that seemed much promising to me. Unfortunately, it does not contain a complete example and I cannot make it run. Here is, what I tried:
I added template.html to wwwroot folder.

**template.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="invoice.css">
</head>
<body style="padding: 3rem">
    <h1>Invoice</h1>
    Awesome company<br />
</body>
</html>
```

I added a button, that invokes `CreatePdf()`. I copied the code from the link above and modified it according to my needs (and because e. g. there is no method LoadOrder(orderId) provided).

**Index.razor**

```
@page "/"
@using Scriban
@using System.IO
@using Microsoft.Playwright
@inject HttpClient Http

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="CreatePdf">pdf</button>

@code{ 
private async Task CreatePdf()
{
    //var templateContent = File.ReadAllText("template.html");
    var templateContent = await Http.GetStringAsync("template.html");
    var template = Template.Parse(templateContent);

    //var templateData = new { Invoice = LoadOrder(orderId) };
    //var pageContent = template.Render(templateData);
    var pageContent = "testString";

    //var dataUrl = "data:text/html;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pageContent));
    var dataUrl = "data:text/html;base64," + pageContent;
```

I added the following two lines, because "browser" was not declared ([Source from playwright](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-browser#browser-contexts)).

```
// Here, the app crashes.
using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
var browser = await playwright.Webkit.LaunchAsync();

await using var context = await browser.NewContextAsync();
var page = await context.NewPageAsync();
await page.GotoAsync(dataUrl, new PageGotoOptions { WaitUntil = WaitUntilState.NetworkIdle });

var output = await page.PdfAsync(new PagePdfOptions
{
    Format = "A4",
    Landscape = false,
});

await File.WriteAllBytesAsync("output.pdf", output);
} }
```

How can i make above code run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use Playwright from a browser (js / wasm). So, you have to use another solution. For instance, you can use [jsPDF](https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/jsPDF.html). This library is not perfect when converting html to pdf, but maybe it will be ok for your usage.

Add a few script references in `index.html` to use jsPDF (you can also install them using npm if you prefer)

```html
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>

<!-- jsPDF references -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dompurify@2.3.3/dist/purify.min.js"></script>
```

Create a file `wwwroot/HtmlToPdf.js` with the following content:

```js
export function generateAndDownloadPdf(htmlOrElement, filename) {
    const doc = new jspdf.jsPDF({
        orientation: 'p',
        unit: 'pt',
        format: 'a4'
    });

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        doc.html(htmlOrElement, {
            callback: doc => {
                doc.save(filename);
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}

export function generatePdf(htmlOrElement) {
    const doc = new jspdf.jsPDF();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        doc.html(htmlOrElement, {
            callback: doc => {
                const output = doc.output("arraybuffer");
                resolve(new Uint8Array(output));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Then, you can use the script from a Razor component:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<button type="button" @onclick="DownloadPdf">Generate</button>

@code {
    async Task DownloadPdf()
    {
        await using var module = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./HtmlToPdf.js");

        // Generate and download the PDF
        await module.InvokeVoidAsync("generateAndDownloadPdf", "<h1>sample</h1>", "sample.pdf");

        // Generate the PDF and get its content as byte[] (need .NET 6 to support Uint8Array)
        var bytes = await module.InvokeAsync<byte[]>("generatePdf", "<h1>sample</h1>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The console shows error in this line: `await using var module = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./HtmlToPdf.js");` the error is `TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://localhost:7178/HtmlToPdf.js
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)
   at admin.garage_solot.ch.Pages.InvoiceCreate.DownloadPdf() in C:\admin` does anyone know the cause?

Comment: I think it can either be the '.' for "./HtmlToPdf.js" so try to replace it with "/HtmlToPdf.js". And i personally removed the "await using" from the first line. So : "var module = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/HtmlToPdf.js");"

Comment: Also think about replacing "data:application/pdf;base64" to "data:application/octet-stream;base64" if you are loading array of bytes. See below : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70891924/convert-byte-array-back-to-pdf-in-blazor

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post describing a way to do this using rotativa.io service (disclaimer: I'm the author of the service)

[Creating PDF files in Blazor](https://rotativa.io/site/blog/instructions/2023/03/15/create-pdf-in-blazor.html)