# How to export a table as pdf in blazor wasm

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I am new to Blazor.

I want to generate a PDF of a table. I am using Mudblazor for UI.

I search and find this [How can I create a pdf for download in blazor wasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69886010/how-can-i-create-a-pdf-for-download-in-blazor-wasm)

But this answer gave an error.

Is there any way to export pdf in Mudblazor table? https://dev.mudblazor.com/components/table#api

Can anyone share any example for export pdf in blazor?